# Can't access 'createSyncAccessHandle' on type FileSystemFileHandle

Tags: javascript, native-file-system-api-js, origin-private-file-system

Property 'createSyncAccessHandle' does not exist on type 'FileSystemFileHandle'.ts(2339)

```
const root = await navigator.storage.getDirectory();

const File1 = await root.getFileHandle('file.txt', { create: true });

const accessHandle = await File1.createSyncAccessHandle();
```

Based on the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileHandle/createSyncAccessHandle) we have `createSyncAccessHandle` method but is not found, whether I am missing something

[image]

Comment: are you running on https?

Comment: How does a matter ? OPFS is within browser right

Comment: the docs state `Secure context: This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers.`

Answer (score 1):

The docs state:

> The createSyncAccessHandle() method of the FileSystemFileHandle interface returns a Promise which resolves to a FileSystemSyncAccessHandle object that can be used to synchronously read from and write to a file. The synchronous nature of this method brings performance advantages, **but it is only usable inside dedicated Web Workers** for files within the origin private file system.

So my question is, are you runnning this inside a Web Worker?

Comment: No i am directly using it in my react code

Comment: You cannot do that

Comment: @rambo you need to do that in a service worker not in react.

Answer (score 0):

You used `createSyncAccessHandle()` in `FileSystemDirectoryHandle`: `getDirectoryHandle()` method but `createSyncAccessHandle()` is in

```
FileSystemFileHandle: createSyncAccessHandle().
```

So, i think you need to change to:

```
const root = await navigator.storage.getDirectory();

const Directory = await root.getDirectoryHandle('folder', {
  create: true
});


const File = await root.getFileHandle('file.txt', {
  create: true
});

const accessHandle = await File.createSyncAccessHandle();
```

Comment: Getting the same error
Property 'createSyncAccessHandle' does not exist on type 'FileSystemFileHandle'.ts(2339)

Comment: So sorry i cant help you. Please wait for someone who know the solution.